# How to turn groups of rows into separate columns?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a postgresql table that looks like this:

```
a|b|c|result
0|3|6|50
0|3|7|51
0|4|6|52
0|4|7|53
1|3|6|54
1|3|7|55
1|4|6|56
1|4|7|57
```

Is there an easy way to SELECT something like:

```
a|result for b=3|result for b=4
0|sum(50,51)    |sum(52,53)
1|sum(54,55)    |sum(56,57)
```

In other words, how to convert the groups of values of b into columns of aggregate functions like sum(), avg(), or others?

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I'd suggest a crosstab query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question completely, but I think you are looking for [`case`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html).

```
-- drop table if exists sample;

create table sample
  (a int,
   b int,
   c int,
   result int);

insert into sample values
(0,3,6,50),
(0,3,7,51),
(0,4,6,52),
(0,4,7,53),
(1,3,6,54),
(1,3,7,55),
(1,4,6,56),
(1,4,7,57)
;

select
  a,
  sum(case when b = 3 then result end) as result_for_b3,
  sum(case when b = 4 then result end) as result_for_b4
from
  sample
group by
  a
```

Result:

```
a;result_for_b3;result_for_b4
1;109;113
0;101;105
```

And if you (but I hope you don't) need to have output exactly as in your question, than you need to use `string_agg` function:

```
select
  a,
  'aggreg(' || string_agg(case when b = 3 then result end::varchar, ',') || ')' as result_for_b3,
  'aggreg(' || string_agg(case when b = 4 then result end::varchar, ',') || ')' as result_for_b4
from
  sample
group by
  a
```

Result:

```
a;result_for_b3;result_for_b4
0;aggreg(50,51);aggreg(52,53)
1;aggreg(54,55);aggreg(56,57)
```

Comment: Thank you Tomas! your straightforward answer made my day.